# Meaning of のが in this sentence?

Tags: song

I’m wondering what the meaning of のが would be in this:

> 世界が君の小さな肩に乗っているのが

I understand the whole sentence and translated it just toc check but for some reason I can’t seem to think what on Earth the のが at the end does.

I’d like to clarify that it’s part of the lyrics of the song We’ll Be Alright by RADWIMPS
「 世界が君の小さな肩に 乗っているのが
僕にだけは見えて 泣き出しそうでいると」
Is the first two lines of the song

Comment: Doesn't look like a whole sentence to me. Are you sure that's the whole sentence?

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't it the same の as in e.g. んだ? Without の it would be "The world is carried on your small shoulders, but ..." and with の it's "It is that the world is carried on your small shoulders, but ..."

Answer (score 2):

The の is a nominalizer and the が is the subject marker. The 乗っているの is the subject of the verb 見える.

Similar examples:

> (人)が立っている**のが見える** *lit.* "someone standing is visible"
> (人)が歌っている**のが聞こえる** *lit.* "someone singing is audible"

見える means "can see" or "visible", and 僕に(だけは) indicates who can see it / who it's visible to.

> 世界が君の小さな肩に乗っている**のが**僕にだけは**見えて**

Literally: That the world is on your little shoulders is visible only to me.
Only I can see that the world is on your little shoulders.